# Boostrap datetimepicker not triggering asp textbox's onTextChanged event

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my textbox to automatically postback after selecting a date from the bootstrap datetimepicker ([Downloaded from here](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)). I stil have to press enter for the event to trigger.

```
        <div class="span3">Date<br />
        <div id="datepicker" class="input-append date">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Isn't that [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx)? `Use the AutoPostBack property to specify whether an automatic postback to the server will occur when the TextBox control loses focus. Pressing the ENTER or the TAB key while in the TextBox control is the most common way to change focus.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a datetime the input control not lose focus, so the postback not occur. You can force a postback in the event triggered from the datepicker like (not tested):

```
el.on('changeDate', function(e) {
    __doPostBack('<%= txtDate.ClientId %>','');
});
```

where `el` is the element on you bind the datetime picker.

Alternatively you can force a blur like:

```
el.on('changeDate', function(e) {
    $('<%= txtDate.ClientId %>').blur();
});
```

Ref: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/